# Windows - Git doesn't show current branch in file path which should be default

Tags: terminal, git-bash, git-for-windows

I have reinstalled Git multiple times and even tried downgrading but to no avail.

This is what a normal Git bash looks like:
[normal git bash from google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCdvm.png)

and this is what mine looks on Git bash terminal and Git bash terminal on IDE:

[my git bash terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGOOU.png)

It also doesn't have color anymore. Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure the duplicate is correct, but that's mainly because the question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You run the wrong file. You should start C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe

I also change my default kernel in Windows 11. I explain below:

1. Windows + R
2. Write wt
3. Click arrow then settings
4. Default Profile -> Git Bash
5. Default terminal application Windows Terminal (I recommend :))